# redis-server auto restart

Tags: redis, centos, centos5

i have a question here..

i already install redis-server on my CentOS vps for my wordpress frontend cache..
but i have a little problem here..

sometimes my redis-server was closed/disconnected suddenly, and i must have to restart it manually using command

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

my question is..

how to auto start the redis-server if my redis-server down or crashed suddenly..

i install redis using this tutorial 
http://www.saltwebsites.com/2012/install-redis-245-service-centos-6

great thanks before

Comment: Worked like charm

Answer (score 2):

> how to auto start the redis-server if my redis-server down or crashed
>   suddenly

Try to look at tools like [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) which can be used to respawn redis if it dies unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use docker with docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    container_name: "redis"
    image: redis:5.0.3-alpine
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6339:6379"
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/redis:/data
    restart:
      always
```

look at the last line:
**restart: always**

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know exactly with centos with linux

```sh
sudo systemctl enable redis_6379
```

The above worked like charm ,The above will create a symlink in /etc/systemd/system/redis_6379.service.

Comment: Well, all this does is start it when the server is restarted....